# Objective C : Given a Class id, can I check if this class implements a certain protocol? Or has a certain selector?

Tags: objective-c, class, protocols, objectfactory

I want to use this for an object factory: Given a string, create a Class, and if
this Class supports a protocol (with a Create() method) then alloc the class and call
Create.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
Class klass = NSClassFromString(classname);
if ([klass instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(create)]) {
  [[klass alloc] create];
}
```

May I, however, point out just how many awful Objective-C rules you're breaking by doing the above? For example, you should never be calling methods on an allocated-but-not-initialized instance. The Xcode Static Analyzer will give you all sorts of warnings about memory leaks.

A better option would be this:

```
[[[klass alloc] init] create];
```

But you seem to imply that you don't want to call init.

You could consider a class method: `[klass create]`, which would return a non-owned instance of `klass`. Then you'd just check `[klass respondsToSelector:@selector(create)]` before calling it.

Comment: Thanks. You're right, the Create method should be a class method.
I think this is usually how object factories are designed.

Comment: This is not the best answer. Chuck is better.

Answer (score 272):

```
NSString *className; //assume this exists
Class class = NSClassFromString(className);
if ([class conformsToProtocol:@protocol(SomeProtocol)]) {
    id instance = [[class alloc] init];
    [instance create];
}
```

Comment: He asked two questions in his title :)

Comment: One step further: `id<SomeProtocol> instance = [[class alloc] init]`

Comment: If you don't have or know the class name, then use [instance class] or NSStringFromClass([instance class])